# Can I use sequence functionality to populate a varchar?

Tags: sql, db2

The following query works for numerical data type (int, bigint, etc).  I would like to do the same thing but apply it to a varchar.  Is this possible and how?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE acct_seq
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 NO MAXVALUE
 NO CYCLE
 CACHE 24
;

SELECT accntnum  AS new_acct, old_acct
FROM FINAL TABLE (
UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)
SET accntnum = NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq, old_acct = accntnum
)
ORDER BY old_acct;
```

on the line `UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)` instead of an int i want to use a `VARCHAR(size)`. The size will be between 4 and 100.

Comment: . . Did you try something like `cast(NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq as varchar(255))`?  I imagine that you can convert the sequence value to whatever type you like.

Comment: I tried that but get error `A value with data type "SYSIBM.INTEGER" cannot be CAST to type "SYSIBM.VARCHAR`

Comment: figured it out.   If i cast it first to a CHAR and then to a VARCHAR it works fine.

Comment: There're also various conversion functions, such as `varchar()` and `varchar_format()`, and the latter's alias `to_char()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cast the INT to a CHAR, then to a VARCHAR.

`SET accntnum = cast(cast(NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq as CHAR(255)) as VARCHAR(255)), old_acct = accntnum`